# How to Regular Expression to get all URL src in <Img> tag in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Regular Expression for handle filter HTML string with JavaScript, i want to get all URL image from `src` attribute in `<img>` tag, but i want to support both charecters `< >` and `&lt; &gt;`. My sample code like below:

```
const filterImages = str => {
  const imgRegExp = /\&(?:quot|[gl]t);img.*?src="(.*?)"[^>]+>/g;
  const images = [];
    let img;
    while ((img = imgRegExp.exec(str))) {
      images.push(img[1]);
    }
  return images;
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Add `<` alternative and that is it. I don't think you need to check the string after the `src` attribute.

Comment: It's return empty array if HTML string same like:
<img src="https://url-image.com/image.jpg"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a bulky regex like this

```regex
(?:<img\s+src="(.*?)"[^.]*?\/?>|&lt;img\s+src="(.*?)"[^.]*?\/?&gt;)
```

I have tested it on a page's html and it seems fine
https://regex101.com/r/zifqle/1

[image]

For convenience you could use named capturing groups, but it seems that they must be unique so the best I can think of is

```regex
(?:<img\s+src="(?<url1>.*?)"[^.]*?\/?>|&lt;img\s+src="(?<url2>.*?)"[^.]*?\/?&gt;)
```

Also try to include `m` (multiline) flag with the regex

Comment: Glad to hear that ! Then ... could you accept the answer)